# Flat/Merge Array of Arrays and primitve types

Tags: php, laravel

i have an Array like this:

```
[ [ "id": 1, "name": "Kategorie 1", "parent_id": null, [ "id": 2, "name": "Kategorie 1.1", "parent_id": 1, [ "id": 5, "name": "Kategorie 1.1.1", "parent_id": 2, [ "id": 11, "name": "Kategorie 1.1.1.1", "parent_id": 5,  [] ], [ "id": 12, "name": "Kategorie 1.1.1.2", "parent_id": 5, [] ] , ........]
```

So this is a Category Hierachy like:

```
Category 1
 Category 1.1
 Category 1.2
  Category 1.2.1
   Category 1.2.1.1.
Category 2
 Category 2.1.
  Category 2.1.1.
 Category 2.2
 Category 2.3.
```

But the depth of the Categories is variable.

So is there a way to flat/merge the Array to:

```
[ [ "id": 1, "name": "Kategorie 1", "parent_id": null], [ "id": 2, "name": "Kategorie 1.1", "parent_id": 1],  [ "id": 5, "name": "Kategorie 1.1.1", "parent_id": 2], [ "id": 11, "name": "Kategorie 1.1.1.1", "parent_id": 5], [ "id": 12, "name": "Kategorie 1.1.1.2", "parent_id": 5] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```php
<?php
$array = [
    [
        "id" => 1, "name" => "Kategorie 1", "parent_id" => null,
        [
            "id" => 2, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1", "parent_id" => 1,
            [
                "id" => 5, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1.1", "parent_id" => 2,
                [
                    "id" => 11, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1.1.1", "parent_id" => 5, []
                ],
                [
                    "id" => 12, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1.1.2", "parent_id" => 5, []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

function flatMerge(array $array, array &$result = [])
{
    $subResult = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $sub) {
        if (is_array($sub)) {
            flatMerge($sub, $result);
        } else {
            $subResult[$key] = $sub;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $subResult;
    return $result;
}

$result = flatMerge($array); // flat merge the array
var_dump($result);
$result = array_filter($result, static function (array $array) { // remove empty arrays
    return !empty($array);
});
var_dump($result);
$result = array_values($result); // reset array keys
var_dump($result);
```

You can see the result of this code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4eaddb4a52f5e9cf9a80644190e526613381c60

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your array like this:

```
$arr = [ 
  [ 
    "id" => 1, "name" => "Kategorie 1", "parent_id" => null, 
    "children" => [
      "id" => 2, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1", "parent_id" => 1, 
      "children" => [ 
        "id" => 5, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1.1", "parent_id" => 2, 
        children => [
          [ "id" => 11, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1.1.1", "parent_id" => 5, "children" => [] ], 
          [ "id" => 12, "name" => "Kategorie 1.1.1.2", "parent_id"=> 5, "children" => [] ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

The following function may work in your case, using recursion function:

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $branch = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $children = [];
        if (isset($item["children"]) && is_array($item["children"])) {
            $children = flatten($item["children"]);
            unset($item["children"]);
        }
        $branch = array_merge($branch, [$item], $children);
    }

    return $branch;
}
```